# What do you do with 'You've created a service' wcf help page?

Tags: c#, wcf

When you created a wcf service, hosted it in IIS and then opened service page in browser you will see a default wcf help page. This page says 'You've created a service'.
What do u do with page? Do u hide it? Or replace it with your own?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not even sure you CAN hide them; you have to be able to access the URL in order to invoke the service properly, and the .svc markups don't allow ASP content to be displayed instead of the basic metadata pages. I think the only way you could do it is with a service in front of IIS, evaluating requests and redirecting "naked" service requests to a catcher page.

Being able to browse to the page is a useful diagnostic and DIY tool. If you can see the page from the browser of the computer with the client software, then you should be able to connect to that service using the client software. So, unless you can think of a security or aesthetic reason why the page cannot be exposed in your production site, I'd just leave it be.